# SqlTableDependency Permission Issues

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, permissions

I am trying to use the SqlTableDependency class  in my C# .Net application and I am unable to grant myself the required database permissions needed. Specifically, I need permissions:

- ALTER
- CONTROL
- CREATE CONTRACT
- CREATE MESSAGE TYPE
- CREATE PROCEDURE
- CREATE QUEUE
- CREATE SERVICE
- EXECUTE
- SELECT
- SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS
- VIEW DATABASE STATE
- VIEW DEFINITION
- CONNECT

The error message states:

> "An unhandled exception of type
>   'TableDependency.SqlClient.Exceptions.UserWithNoPermissionException'
>   occurred in TableDependency.SqlClient.dll. Additional information:
>   User with no CREATE MESSAGE TYPE permission"

I have tried granting myself the permission using this query:

```
GRANT CREATE MESSAGE TYPE TO dbo
```

but I get this error:

> "Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner,
>   information_schema, sys, or yourself."

I have confirmed that dbo is the owner of my database.

I am running Sql Server 2008 R2.

How can I grant myself permissions to my server?

Comment: is this a server you set up?

Comment: Yes, I set this up myself.

Comment: when you installed sql server, did you set up an admin account?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure to do this:

Enable broker

```
ALTER DATABASE Your_db_name SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
Go
```

Add to db_owner

```
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER Your_user_db_name
GO
```

Set authorization

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::Your_db_name TO Your_user_db_name;
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever credentials you used in your connection string needs to be db_owner of database. I made that user as db_owner and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

My problem too.

When downgrade SqlTableDependency verson from 4.6.7.8 to 4.6.7, my code is running well :)

Comment: please post these things in comment section